# Getting 256 Colors in Emacs *shell*

Tags: emacs

My Emacs installation has full color support (list-colors-display shows this). However, Emacs *shell* only appears to be able to handle the basic 8 ANSI color escapes. I have those handled by the following in my .emacs:

```
(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Is there a way to increase the number of colors supported in *shell*?

Comment: Is Emacs running in a terminal already or as an X / OS X / Win32 frame?

Comment: I also cannot get M-x shell, M-x eshell, M-x term, M-x ansi term to produce 256 colors. But yesterday I tried M-x vterm and it can. You will need to compile and install https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm first. You might need to recompile your Emacs first if it was not compiled with `--with-modules` option. It probably does not work on Windows (haven't checked).

Answer (score 5):

To get 256-color in terminal you must use appropriate terminal emulator.

Check if your terminal suport this:

```
  $ infocmp -1 $TERM | grep colors
colors#8,
```

For example **xterm** allow this, but you must set **TERM=xterm-256color**.

Comment: I did not downvote but Derek is asking not about any terminal emulator, but about emacs shell-mode.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading correctly setting ansi flags/settings will only allow 8 colors,get rid of them and replace with this setting `tty-color-mode 256`

From:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Colors.html

Comment: Hmm, no I haven't been able to get it to work playing around with this variable. I think this has more to do with the colors emacs itself supports than the colors that \*shell\* supports. If you're able to do it this way, can you elaborate?